# Mobile App Security for Spotify

Tags: mobile, iphone, mobile-app

This is a little bit crazy.

- A long time ago, I created a Spotify account using Facebook credentials.
- A few years ago, I stopped my premium subscription, deleted Spotify from all devices and didn't use it again.
- 3 years ago, I bought a used iPhone.
- Two weeks ago, I installed an application to track running called "Nike Run Club". I use it to track my running. The app connects to Spotify to play music.
- I installed Spotify on my iPhone (never installed Spotify before on the phone).

While preparing for running, I launched Spotify from the Nike app. Spotify prompted to log in.

To log in, I used Facebook credentials (I am not 100% sure what happens next, because I started running). 4 days later I checked my account on Spotify and was shocked to see an email and an account which I didn't recognize. I thought at first it is something Nike Run Club created.

On my iPhone I was directed to the Spotify web app and saw details for an account which didn't belong to me in any way. It had a person's name which looked real and a corresponding email was registered.

I looked on "Receipts" and found multiple receipts being 0 dollars. I didn't think twice and just logged out and in again using my Facebook credentials again. This time I was logged in with the correct credentials.

Afterwards I checked my Visa payments. The Visa I used a few years ago when I had the premium subscription is not valid anymore. I checked my current Visa I used for the last few months and nothing was there from Spotify.

In my Spotify account is no recent and valid payment method registered.

Any idea what did happen?

After this experience, I logged in to my Facebook account and removed all applications which use Facebook login except Spotify.

One more thing I remember: I bought the iPhone second-hand. So could it be that I used the stored info from the previous owner (even though I bought it 3 years ago)?

Comment: This is something you need to ask Spotify about, they have the means to know what happened.

Comment: "I checked my account on Spotify and was shocked to see an email and an account which I didn't recognize" -- what does that mean? "On my iPhone I was directed to the Spotify web app and saw details for an account which didn't belong to me in any way. It had a person's name which looked real and a corresponding email was registered." -- was it the same account? I'm afraid some of the details here are very confusing. It could be that someone gained access to your Spotify account and added themselves.

Comment: "This time I was logged in with the correct credentials." -- did you use the wrong credentials last time? What payment method was entered into your Spotify account with all those $0 receipts?

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible, as long as you or the seller of the phone did not reset the iPhone to factory settings.**

What's a little bit strange about this is the fact that you had to sign in on first launch with your credentials. But generally speaking as long as the user allows it, apps for iOS may choose to store account data even though an app is uninstalled.

Comment: I might be wrong about the app ask me to login. As I said, I started running and honestly didn't pay attention to what I clicked. so It might be that spotify didn't ask me about credentials and just logged in using stored credentials.

Comment: "*apps for iOS may choose to store account data even though an app is uninstalled*" I had this problem with an app that was broken, I couldn't use it, and uninstalling+reinstalling didn't clear data, and there wasn't a button in the app settings (like on Android) to clear data so I just couldn't use it anymore at all (it was actually for work; kind of a pain not to have my work agenda on mobile). So far as I found at the time, uninstalling an app ought to delete data. Do you have a reference for this where I can learn more about it?